# Why doesn't WiFi work on Dell 4020?

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell 4020 laptop using Windows installer for Ubuntu. But my WiFi device is not working. What should I do?

```
$ lspci | grep -i net

07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

Comment: I won't even call this an answer because it is just a personal comment.  I use (and buy for my kids) used Dell laptops because the cost, performance, and compatibility are first rate.  However the first thing I always do is find out what the Intel wireless option was and get one on ebay for a few bucks.  Many of the Broadcom can be made to work but in the last 8 I bought the Intel were flawless. May not be an option but might help others.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Why do you think this is a duplicate? Those two computers have different Wifi cards.

Answer (score 0):

Start the "Additional Drivers" application and install the driver for Broadcom wireless cards which should be in the list.

Comment: the Error Comes "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system"  and no Driver in the given List